# Is this XSS filter safe or not?

Tags: xss, secure-coding

I have a classified site, I was wondering if this is secure enough or not, between I got this filter from a friend of mine.

```
var a = window.location.hash.replace(/[^\w\-#]/g, "_");
a = a + ".expandable";
if (0 < jQuery(a).length) {
  a = jQuery(a).find(".exw-control");
  if (0 < a.length) a.trigger("expand",null);
}
```

It looks like the first line filters out all characters except word characters (\w), - and # by replacing them with an underscore, before passing them to the jQuery function.
Is an attacker able to bypass that filter and get some javascript to execute (e.g. an alert), I need to know if yes because of the sensitive content of my site.

Comment: Have you tried the XSS Cheat Sheet tests against the code?

Comment: @schroeder No, I haven't. So you think it's vulnerable or not?

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass user input to the jQuery or `$` function if you don't want it to possibly be interpreted as HTML. Use `$.find(a)` instead, and then you don't have to worry about filtering it. Though you should do this in a try-catch block because the user could give an invalid selector.

Also, it's good practice to avoid re-using variables like `a` for different purposes.

```
try {
  var a = window.location.hash + ".expandable";
  if (0 < jQuery.find(a).length) {
    var control = jQuery.find(a).find(".exw-control");
    control.trigger("expand",null);
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.error("Error processing hash", e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I cannot change this one, I should keep passing user input to the jQuery.. I did the XSS cheat sheet tests, I cannot see any possible XSS attack, can you also check it?